# What better ways are there to add a column to a pandas.Series?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```py
import pandas
series1 = pandas.Series({
   'a':1,
   'b':2,
})

dict = series1.to_dict()
dict['c'] = 3
series2 = pandas.Series(dict)
```

I need to add a column/index onto `series1`. Current, as shown above, I'm creating `series2` by making a dictionary from `series1`'s data, adding an index, then creating a new series using that dictionary.

Is there a way to add a column or merge two series' columns similar to `pandas.DataFrame.join()` or `pandas.DataFrame.assign()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via the append function.

```
series2 = series1.append(pd.Series({'c':2}))
```

If you wanna use all the dataframe methods then you can convert series object to dataframe objects via -

```
series1.to_frame()
```

Answer (score 1):

It solves this task "I need to add a column/index onto series1"

```
series1.loc['c'] = 3
```